# how to set dropdown month for kendo datePicker without setting a particular date

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker

I have several kendo datePickers on the form and they will always be capturing a date from a prior month.  How to set the datePicker dropdown so that it defaults to a particular month *without setting the picker to a particular date*?

Comment: Lets see if I get you right: You want to change the month of the datepikcer but keep its current day or year ?

Comment: "Today" can remain today. When the dropdown displays, it should display a particular year/month with no particular date selected. In other words, I don't want to set the picker's value, merely its (default) dropdown month. The user should be able to navigate backwards and forwards to other months. I don't want to change navigation in any way. But if it's December now, I might want to display September, depending on the requirements of the particular field.  I'm tracking events that happened around 90 days in the past, on average. There are quite a few datePickers and users tire of navigating.